# Why the command: type “%filename%” failed

Tags: batch-file

The command

```
type “File Name with Spaces.txt”
```

Works!!

But

```
set  “Fname=File Name with Spaces.txt”

type “%Fname%”
```

Or

```
type “!Fname!”
```

Failed !!

Message: `The system cannot find the file specified`

??

Comment: You appear to be using `smart quotes` with a word-processor. Use only `"` and save the code in ASCII, not unicode.

Comment: @Magoo How do i logout?

Comment: `exit` should quit the `cmd` session.

Answer (score 0):

```
set Fname=File Name with Spaces.txt
type "%Fname%"
```

should work. You don't really need the quotes in the set command in this case. But they are important when you access the variable's content in the `type` command.

**Edit**:
I am back at a pc where I can test things again. @Squashman and @Mofi are right about the main point that you should use *straight double quotes* (`"`) and in saying that the `set "Fname=File Name & Spaces.txt"` is a legitimate and often the recommended syntax. However I would also like to mention another possible variation on the theme. When you do

```
set Fname="File Name & Spaces.txt"
```

The quotes will become part of the stored variable:

```
echo %Fname%
> "File Name & Spaces.txt"
```

and the `type` command referencing a filename containing a blank and an ampersand can then be issued without the quotes:

```
type %Fname%
```

If you want to acces the contents *without*  the surrounding quotes you can still do

```
echo %Fname:"=%
> File Name with Spaces.txt
```

(see `set /?` for further details on variable handling in cmd.)

Comment: Sorry, haven't got access to a computer at the moment. I am answering from my Android smartphone. But so far set commands like this have worked for me in many cases.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting quotes around the SET command. It protects special chatacters and does no harm using them.

Comment: Please read answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) The syntax `set "Fname=File Name & Spaces.txt"` (straight quotes) is highly recommended for various reasons and necessary if file name contains a Windows command line operator like `&` which should be interpreted as literal character and not as operator.